# Problemas con el registro de usuario persistiendo la data - react

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, graphql

estoy desarrollando una app que actualmente tiene su `signIn form` que funciona de buena manera:

- Cada vez que el user ingresa -> se actualiza el state en el context y se crea un objeto en el `localStorage`.

Pero el problema me llego al crear el flujo del registro de un user, ya que cuando se crea un usuario y este form llama a la funcion que dispara el servicio (donde se le pasan los argumentos) me actualiza el state `isLogged` **pero como es sabido cuando se actualiza la pagina ese state vuelve a su estado inicial** por lo que, el usuario queda desconectado de su sesion:

**SIGN IN metodo:**

```
         signIn = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { store: { loginData } } = this.state;
            const { signinUser, history } = this.props;

            const variables = {
                email: loginData.email,
                password: loginData.password
            };
            
            try {
                const response = await signinUser({variables});
                
                if(response) {
                const { data: {signinUser:{token}} } = response;
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                this.setState({
                    store: {
                        isLogged: true
                    }
                });
                history.push('/books/home');
                }
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }
```

Como pueden ver con el sign in al entrar el usuario, recibe un token (que se genera en el metodo create user en donde se encripta informacion del user).

Pero con el signUp, esto no ocurre... existira una manera de poder tener como un token de sesion o algo para signup cosa que cuando se refresque la pagina el user siga conectado?

**SIGN UP metodo:**

```
        signUp = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { store: { signUpData } } = this.state;
            const { createUser, history } = this.props;

            console.log(signUpData.firstName)
    
            const variables = {
                firstName: signUpData.firstName,
                email: signUpData.email,
                password: signUpData.password
            };
            try {
                const response = await createUser({variables});
                if(response) {
                    this.setState({
                        store: {
                            isLogged: true
                        }
                    })
                    history.push('/books/home');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto.. lo que hice fue crear un token a partir del atributo email del objeto user que se creaba en el servicio, para luego el servicio me retorne un objeto con los atributos `user` y `session_token`

```
       def resolve(first_name: nil, auth_provider: nil)
        user = User.create!(
          first_name: first_name,
          email: auth_provider&.[](:credentials)&.[](:email),
          password: auth_provider&.[](:credentials)&.[](:password)
        )
        
        crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base.byteslice(0..31))
        session_token = crypt.encrypt_and_sign("user_name: #{user.email}")

        return { user: user, session_token: session_token }
      end
```